# Reanimated V2.0.0-rc.0 different thread error when using hooks provided in reanimated v2

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

Im using Reaniamted v2 with an expo project. I have seen many tutorials online where the example below works with no errors but when i'm trying to use the code as a learning practice in my app I get error "Tried to synchronously call function {inOut} from a different thread. Solution is: a) if you want to synchronously execute this method, mark it as a Worklet
b) If you want to execute this method on the JS thread, wrap it using runOnJS"

The error is caused by the "withTiming(animation.value....." hook placed on the x translation, in all the videos i've watched this usage of the hooks is permitted. Why am I getting this error if Im not misusing it?

```
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Animated, {
    useSharedValue,
    useAnimatedStyle,
    withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated'

const Transitions = () => {
    const animation = useSharedValue(0)

    const animationStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: withTiming(
                        animation.value,
                        {
                            duration: 1000,
                        },
                        () => {
                            animation.value = 0
                        }
                    ),
                },
            ],
        }
    })

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => {
                    animation.value = 200
                }}
            >
                <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animationStyle]} />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    box: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: '#631d94',
    },
})
```

also I should mention I just tried to install reanimated on a fresh project just to give it another try and I recieevd all the following warnings.

```
pm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.31: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/.bin/uuid as it wasn't installed by /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/uuid
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/.bin/semver as it wasn't installed by /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/semver
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/.bin/mime as it wasn't installed by /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/mime
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/.bin/json5 as it wasn't installed by /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/json5

> core-js@3.9.1 postinstall /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/@expo/configure-splash-screen/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /Users/hb/Desktop/React Native Projects/test2/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN react-native-reanimated@2.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-reanimated@2.0.0-rc.0 requires a peer of react-native-gesture-handler@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-asset@8.2.2 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-file-system@9.3.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-error-recovery@1.4.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @unimodules/react-native-adapter@5.7.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-font@8.4.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-keep-awake@8.4.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-linking@2.0.1 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-linear-gradient@8.4.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-sqlite@8.5.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN expo-permissions@10.0.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-safe-area-context@3.1.9 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/preset-env@7.13.10 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.13.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.59.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.13.10 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/helper-compilation-targets@7.13.10 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@7.8.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.8.3 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-export-namespace-from@7.8.3 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings@7.8.3 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.8.3 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-logical-assignment-operators@7.10.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-numeric-separator@7.10.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.8.3 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.8.3 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining@7.8.3 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-dotall-regex@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-duplicate-keys@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs@7.13.8 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-new-target@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-property-literals@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-reserved-words@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-escapes@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2@0.1.10 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/preset-modules@0.1.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-plugin-polyfill-regenerator@0.1.6 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3@0.1.7 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin@7.12.17 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider@0.1.5 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.4.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-export-default-from@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-flow@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.12.17 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.13.10 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.13.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-typescript@7.12.13 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/preset-typescript@7.12.17 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ react-native-reanimated@2.0.0-rc.0
added 23 packages from 67 contributors, removed 619 packages and updated 467 packages in 50.707s

52 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Answer (score 1):

FIXED !

My issue was............. I was using npm and not yarn. Couldn't believe it. I spent an entire day troubleshooting this and I hope that other people running into this issue will be spared those painful hours. Im switching over to yarn for good!

If you're using expo, and using npm install yarn and run the following commands:

- yarn add react-native-reanimated@2.0.0-rc.0
- yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
- rm -r node_modules
- watchman watch-del-al
- rm -fr $TMPDIR/metro-cache
- yarn add core-js@^3
- yarn
- expo start -c

Answer (score 0):

i ran the code and works well, how did you installed and configured the reanimated ? show your package.json and your babel.config.js

Comment: I apologize for not providing the package.json and the babel.config. The link below contains all of that since i cant share those in a comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1826